# Rhythmbox keeps repeating same song after play queue is empty

Tags: rhythmbox

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but whenever Rhythmbox is finished playing all the songs in my play queue it immediately jumps to first song in my music library and keeps playing it over and over.

I don't have shuffle or repeat enabled.

Its just plain weird.  Any idea how to make it stop?

I'm using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: have you got repeat-one-song plugin enabled?  Maybe try disabling all plugins and seeing if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Disabled all plugins...still happens.  I do not have the repeat-one-song plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting the same problem since I ticked the "View Queue as Side Pane" option.

Basically, if I start playing music when the Music Library screen is visible then the first song in the music library will be played when the queue is finished.

Try unticking the "View Queue as Side Pane" option (if it's ticked), add music to the queue, then switch to the Play Queue screen and hit play from there.

It's a bit annoying to keep flicking between the Music and Play Queue screens but that works for me.

Comment: did you report this bug to the Rhythmbox developers?

Comment: Didn't think of it as a bug (the Music screen is for selecting tracks and then play them in the Play Queue screen) so I haven't reported it.

Comment: Hey dumb ass posting a "me too" respone doens't add value or help!

Comment: Hey @MaxEisenhardt, you're absolutely right, a "me too" response doesn't help. 'Try unticking the "View Queue as Side Pane" option, add music to the queue, then switch to the Play Queue screen and hit play from there.' is the part of my post that adds value. However, I've not used Rhythmbox since 2018 so those instructions might not be relevant now.